# PostgreSQL Upsert DO update

Tags: postgresql

I am attempting to create a trigger function to insert on one schema's table, when there is an insert or update on another schema's table. I was able to get this working, but I had read that it was better practice to use the `ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT DO UPDATE`. When I got a variation of the below working, I tried to refactor to use the `ON CONFLICT`. When that didn't work, I attempted to revert back to this and for some reason, I'm missing something here that is keeping it from working as intended

It's not inserting on namespace1.tbl1 when there's an insert or update on namepsace2.tbl1. I get `invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "namespace2.tbl1"` and it points to the start of the line where col3 is attempting to be set.

```
CREATE 
OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert_namespace1_tbl1() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$ 
BEGIN
     UPDATE namespace1.tbl1
      SET
        col2 = namespace2.tbl1.col2,
        col3 = namespace2.tbl1.col3,
        col4 = namespace2.tbl1.col4,
        col5 = namespace2.tbl1.col5,
        col6 = namespace2.tbl1.col6,
        col7 = namespace2.tbl1.col7,
        col8 = namespace2.tbl1.col8,
        col9 = namespace2.tbl1.col9,
        col10 = namespace2.tbl1.col10
      WHERE
        namespace2.tbl1.col1 = namespace1.tbl1.col1;
        IF NOT FOUND THEN
      INSERT INTO 
        namespace1.tbl1 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11) 
        SELECT
          col1,
          col2,
          col3,
          col4,
          col5,
          col6,
          col7,
          col8,
          col9,
          col10,
          col11
        FROM
            namespace2.tbl1;
        END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END
;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, it's been a long day, lol. It's not inserting on `namespace1.tbl1` when there's an insert or update on `namepsace2.tbl1`. I get `invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "tbl1"` and it points to the start of the line where col3 is attempting to be set. I'll edit question to express this.

Comment: Im not sure if triggers is for namespace 1 or 2. but you should use `NEW.field` instead of the source table.

Comment: The trigger upserts `namespace1.tbl1` when there is a change or insert on `namespace2.tbl1` Using `NEW.field` in place of `namespace2.tbl1` gives error for NEW has no field col1

Comment: Can you show the version of the trigger with the `ON CONFLICT` statement that is causing the error?

Comment: :) No source control on development. :) If you can select namespace2.tbl1.col1 but but cannot use new.col1 means that the trigger did not fire on table namespace2.tbl1. Please post the DDL for both tables and the actual calling trigger.

Comment: Why don't you use `insert ... on conflict`? Whereever you read that the approach in your question is better - that's plain wrong. `insert .. on conflict` is much more efficient, but more importantly it's not prone to race conditions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Sorry I meant that I read `insert..on conflict` was better. But for some reason I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `insert on conflict` instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert_namespace1_tbl1() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$$ 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO namespace1.tbl1 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11) 
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11
  FROM namespace2.tbl1
  ON CONFLICT (col1) 
    DO UPDATE
      SET
        col2 = excluded.col2,
        col3 = excluded.col3,
        col4 = excluded.col4,
        col5 = excluded.col5,
        col6 = excluded.col6,
        col7 = excluded.col7,
        col8 = excluded.col8,
        col9 = excluded.col9,
        col10 = exclude.col10;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This assumes that there is a unique or primary key constraint on `tbl1.col1`

Online example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e4f4364e440163f23e66933afffe4544

Comment: I've tried this. I keep getting `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "namespace2.tbl1"` And yes, col1 is a primary key with unique constraint on `namespace1.tbl1.col.1` The error pointing to `col2 = ^excluded.col2`

Comment: @MikeHeft: works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e4f4364e440163f23e66933afffe4544  (I had to remove the schemas, as that is not allowed on dbfiddle)

Comment: Weird. Thank you for taking the time to create that fiddle, I can see that it works. It must be something small and stupid on my part :P. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I literally copy and pasted your code(replacing with relevant information) and still get the above error :(

Comment: @MikeHeft: my initial answer had an invalid `;` after `from namespac2.tbl1` - did you remove that?

Comment: I did remove that

Comment: I tried it with `NEW.col1,...` in the fiddle and was able to get it to work. But when trying in pgadmin it didn't insert into namespace1.tbl1 :(

Comment: Do you upsert the whole tbl2 table every insert and update?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I finally got it to work. Thank you!. Been a long couple of days at work with lots fo other projects, but I finally read the docs on `excluded` and with that new understand I was able to make it work.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes. In case any of the information changes the two tables need to be in sync

Comment: Yes but is very inefficient to do the whole table instead of only the row changes.

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/eb1dea/1)**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rec_insert()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
     IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN     
       INSERT INTO t2 (id, c1, c2)  VALUES (new.ID, new.c1, new.c2);
     ELSE
       UPDATE t2
       SET c1 = new.c1
         , c2 = new.c2
       WHERE id = new.ID;
     END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER ins_same_rec
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON t1
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE rec_insert();
```